# Dask can't read the whole file

Tags: python, dask

I tried to read a huge file (68.3 GB) by Dask as follows:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
auth_df = dd.read_csv('data/auth.txt', sep =",|@",  engine='python')
```

Reading data was smooth.

Then, from the dataset, I wanted to see the 5 rows with a specific timestamp (150885).

```py
auth_df[auth_df['Time'] == 150885].head()
```

However, the result showed me nothing but an error as follows:

```
/home/fox_kim/anaconda3/envs/py 36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py: 6383: UserWarning: Insufficient elements for 'head'. 5 elements requested, only a elements available. Try passing larger `npartitions' to 'head'. warnings.warn(msg.format(n, len(r)))
```

I am pretty sure that the timestamp is in the dataset.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass parameter `npartitions=X` to `.head()`, where `X` is some reasonable number. For example, if your timestamp appears within the first 5 partitions, then you can try `.head(npartitions=5)`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. The dataset is 70GB, and the timestamp is somewhere between 2GB to 3GB. I think it is challenging for me to figure out where the timestamp occurs. Do you know how I can possibly work around this difficulty? Do you have any other suggestions to deal with large files?